# Stalking, bullying and downvoting on Stack overflow related sites

Tags: discussion, down-votes, abuse

Lately I have noticed something that concerns me - that some regulars on chats actively stalk and downvote certain other users' questions/answers.

While 'stalking' itself is harmless enough - well if you post on a public website, you want your writings to be read. Whether it is guided from the title, tags or from the search engines, or because, well, you are the poster. Stalking down someone, negatively commenting, downvoting his/her answers or questions doesn't seem to be a healthy hobby to me - esepcially when the links are posted on chats and other regulars are expected to participate in the downvoting/negative commenting. This is harassment, it is bullying!

This is different from serial downvoting - which usually happens when a user is angered by another user. It is almost like continuous serial downvoting, from a group of people who don't seem to have better things to do other than sitting in the chat, stalking others and amuse themselves with downvoting certain other users who, for gaining reps or other reasons putting an effort into answering questions.

Also, I have mentioned a couple of victim in the comments beneath. [Here is a section of the transcript in regards to the user 'Your common sense'](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1972143#1972143), [here is some search results in regards to the user 'vlad from moscow' in the C++ lounge](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?room=10&q=vlad) - BTW vlad isn't aware of the C++ lounge.

BTW more upvotes doesn't necessarily mean you are right, see:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKheU.png)
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zw6g.png) & [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XvI2.png)

Comment: I think I know of the instances you're referring to. As I have explained to you, there is no stalking involved. Nor unwarranted downvoting, nor any real anger. The stalking and bullying classifications really don't apply. The discussed posts most certainly don't fall under *"downvoting certain other users who, for gaining reps or other reasons putting an effort into answering questions"*.

Comment: More than 1 instance, the victims in recent days: 'your common sense' & 'Vlad from Moscow' ... could be more, but then I don't monitor all the chats, and with the ones I frequent, I don't read the whole transcripts

Comment: I'm compiling an answer, though I'm only aware of your objections to YCS. I don't know about a Vlad from Moscow?

Comment: there are a lot of things you don't know about

Comment: Also don't forget about evan carroll - although, he probably deserves it.

Comment: Crap needs to be cleaned up. Great content deserves praise. You show me instances where what was done goes against this, and you have a point.

Comment: @Doorknob Given telkitty's response to it, I can only assume part of the motivation for this post comes from [this particular transcript](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1972143#1972143).

Comment: [example](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228778/where-is-the-spam-close-reason-on-a-question)

Comment: What is that an example of exactly @user258837?

Comment: How is the first example an example of chat users actively stalking and downvoting you or others? For that matter, how are any of the other screenshots?

Comment: The first example does not look at all like stalking. People saw what you posted as a guess and a wrong one at that. While I would not have voted like they did, I can see where they are coming from. The current vote count on that question is +13/-2, which indicates that those who downvoted for the most part removed their votes or changed them to upvotes.

Comment: I don't understand any of this. What are the screenshots doing here? Am I too dumb to understand their significance? Is their significance beyond "something happened and I have been collecting random screenshots all this time for no reason"?

Comment: That said, I do appreciate the dedication of taking a screenshot of that DDoS thing a couple of days ago (i.e. a mere 7 minutes after the downvoted answer was posted) and keeping it so you could still post it today when it reflects [a completely different reality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229309/46642). Some people might call that "dishonesty". Wait, I am one of those people.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes You're not alone. I don't see how the other screenshots are evidence of "stalking" and "bullying". I mentioned only the first one because I saw that post when it was posted and could easily get back to it.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes read Barts comment above namely [this section of the script](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1972143#1972143)

Comment: @telkitty, I'm surprised you did not elect to post [this transcript](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89/2013/8/8/1-16). *Who is the elitest troll* indeed.

Comment: No, I won't go chase this issue through the chat transcripts. If there is any evidence of wrongdoing whatsoever, stop playing games and put it in the question.

Comment: So the screenshots have nothing to do with the question at all @telkitty.exe? If so, just remove them please. They only confuse. If there is a point to them, clarify it.

Comment: This appears to be a bag of something. Not cats, I suspect.

Comment: I don't understand why have you posted a screenshot highlighting you threatening people?

Comment: I'm going to vote to close as "unclear what you are asking" because the screenshots in particular make no sense. If you want to edit to explain what they mean I will retract my vote

Answer (score 16):

I can only assume based on recent interactions with you on this topic, that you are referring to [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). This Meta SO chat room seems to be frequented by users (like me) who have a certain interest in the site and network as a whole, as well as how it functions, what could be improved, or what we can collectively do to tackle spam and the like. Whether healthy or not could be up for debate, but generally the users in there mean well and overall they more enjoy the casual chat than anything else.

Admittedly there is the occasional cleanup request. That can either come in the form of a request to close, or perhaps downvote if warranted. As you say in the comments you *"don't read the whole transcripts"*. Fair enough, I don't expect you to. What you might have missed however is that most of your responses to those requests are not blind votes. If the post in question doesn't deserve to be on the site, or is particularly bad, I (and I can only assume several others as well) act on it as we would, were we to have encountered it at random. There is no bullying here, nor downvotes that should not be cast, nothing of the sort.

Additionally, we do on occasion discuss our disagreement with the request and explicitly state we don't think that should happen. Or even that certain downvotes should not happen. It only takes a bit of reading through our history of the last few days to establish that.

As for one of the specific instances I've discussed with you, that particular user - apart from being an amazing contributor when he wants to - time and time again posts content I bump into that does not belong on the site. Not just because it's not an answer to the question, but because it's a rant, or has the effect of poisoning the atmosphere if not controlled. I do care about SO and the network as a whole, so in the light of the Tavern it is not all that strange to discuss this. Or to discuss this user apparently being able to do so time and time again without any visible repercussions. These posts do not belong on the site, and the faster they go, the better.

It would be bullying or stalking if I were to incessantly look at every new post from said user and downvote or flag it. I don't, and I don't see other user in the chatroom doing this. Does a single instance on occasion warrant a look into other recent history? Sometimes. But that's about it.

Very bad content deserves to go, and good content deserves praise. It's as simple as that. And if that is all that happens, I can't see a problem. Perhaps your occasional presence in chat provides a somewhat distorted view, but I can't really see something that's truly problematic. [The transcript is there for all to see](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89). If something is going on that needs addressing, I'd love to hear it.